# Requirejs / AMD - how does it solve global namespace pollution

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd

One of the main benefits of AMD is that it's supposed to prevent global namespace pollution. It might do that by not attaching any module name to the global object, but module names are stored internally. If everyone was to adopt AMD and module loaders, then "define" is practically now the global object.

Looking an built "optimized" file like this:

```
define("app/modA", [], { /**/ }), 
define("app/modC", [], { /**/ }), 
define("app/modB", ["app/modC"], { /**/ }), 
define("app/app", ["app/modA", "app/modB"], { /**/ }), 
require(["app/app"], { /**/ }), 
define("main", function () {});
```

What if this file is included in a larger codebase which already has modules with the same names?

You can pass a namespace option to r.js, which outputs something like:

```
foo.define("app/modA" ...
```

But now you have a global foo? How is that any different than using a single global object literal as a namespace and encapsulation, module patterns etc?

Comment: This question is more appropriate to programmers.stackexchange

Answer (score 0):

Set `wrap: true` in you config. Now when you compile with r.js your `define` will no longer be in the global namespace and none of your module names will conflict with any other module definitions in other files included on the page.

Comment: Ok so that wraps it in a IIFE, but that's it. define is still a reference to the same global define function. Maybe if you included almond within the IIFE that would make define a local function, but that seems crazy to me

Comment: @Fergal almond.js is 1kb of code that will prevent you from polluting the global namespace. I don't think that's crazy to include.